# Overriding a class method in Swift 2.0 generates an error and a crash

Tags: swift, class, methods, swift2

I am trying to override a superclass method in Swift 2.0 but I get an error and a crash so the code does not excuse itself.

Here is the particular piece of code creating the issue.

```
 override func discountedPrice (percentage: Double = 10.0) -> Double {
        return super.discountedPrice(percentage)
    }
```

And the super class and sub class

```
import UIKit


class Product {

    let title : String
    var price : Double = 0.0


    init (title: String, price: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.price = price
    }


    func discountedPrice (percentage: Double) -> Double {
        return price - (price * percentage/100)
    }

}

enum Size{
    case Small, Medium, Large

    init () {

        self = .Small
    }
}

class Clothing: Product {

    var size = Size()

    let designer : String

    init (title: String, price: Double, designer :String){
        self.designer = designer
        super.init(title: title, price: price)
    }



    override func discountedPrice (percentage: Double = 10.0) -> Double {
        return super.discountedPrice(percentage)
    }
}
```

Comment: `discountedPrice (percentage: Double = 10.0)` Is that valid syntax? Are you trying to give all `Clothing` items a 10% discount?

Comment: Originally the method was: override func discountedPrice (_ percentage: Double = 10.0) -> Double {
        return super.discountedPrice(percentage)
    } but the I got a warning and it fixed the code to percentage from _ percentage

Comment: In Swift 2.1 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I get The playground service "com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground" may have generated a crash log. It is probably an issue with my version of Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: Your code works for me in a Playground (Xcode 7.1).